# Write to the last line of a text file?

Tags: python, text, append

I am trying to get the program to automatically start at the last line of a text file when I run it and make it write on the last line. My current code is as follows:

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'a+') as tf
    last_line = tf.readlines()[-1]
    tf.write(linetext + '\n')`
```

When I run this, it says that the list index is out of range. How do I get this to automatically skip to the last line of a text file and start writing from there?

Comment: Yes, just open the file like this `with open('textfile.txt', 'a') as tf:` and then whatever you `.write` to it will be appended at the end of the file.

Comment: @downshift I already did.

Comment: Oh ok, I must have misunderstood, since it showed your link differently. thanks.

Comment: @downshift I think you need more rep to close vote

Comment: I do not want to close a vote. I want the Flag to merge same votes. Perhaps I completely do not understand how identical Flag requests work. I expected to see the number next to my flag increment when another user Flags with the same duplicate link.

Comment: @downshift Flagging is different. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: Anyway, back to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566011/2308683

Answer (score 3):

Use the `a` flag while opening the file

```
with open('path/to/file', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write("This is the new last line\n")
```