# How to add a word at end of a text file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 500 text files in one folder, each of them looks like this:

```
1-1,2-4,In,_,
1-2,5-9,this,_,
1-3,10-15,paper,_,
1-4,16-18,we,_,
1-5,19-26,propose,_,
1-6,27-28,a,Project[1],
```

I need to add one word at the end of the text in each of the files. The result I expect is:

```
1-1,2-4,In,_,
1-2,5-9,this,_,
1-3,10-15,paper,_,
1-4,16-18,we,_,
1-5,19-26,propose,_,
1-6,27-28,a,Project[1],
end
```

How do I write inside the `with` block?

```
import os

path = "All_TSV_Files"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".txt")]
for file in files:
    with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        ### add "end" to end of the file
```

or should I use pandas data frame to do them?

Comment: Also useful [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1466000/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

Say your file is called `"foo.txt"`, you can open it with intend of *appending* to it like this:

```py
with open("foo.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("\nend")
```

The `\n` denotes a newline before inserting `end`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer should be helpful:
[Write to the last line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198007/write-to-the-last-line-of-a-text-file)

Just open file in append mode (pointer will be in the ned of file) and write line.